# Delphi, Export HTML table to Excel

Tags: html, excel, delphi

All I want to do is to implement "Export to excel" option of a classical webbrowser, to Delphi2007 commands...... When I am using this option from a webbrowser to export a 12000 rows table it takes less than a minute to export the table from any web browser from windows. Trying to implement this in Delphi using 2D Array it takes 10 minutes... Trying to implement the export with parsing technique (Stringlists, strings, Pos(tr), pos (td) & some other string functions) it takes a long... Hence, which are the commands of a webbrowser to export an html table to excel that I have to convert them to Delphi? Should I use javascript inside Delphi? Should I use pointers? Should I use HTML entities? xml?...Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

2D ARRAY

```
Excel:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application'); 
ovTable := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.tags('TABLE').item(0);
arrayn:=VarArrayCreate([1, ovTable.Rows.Length, 1, ovTable.Rows.Item(1).Cells.Length],         varvariant);
for i:=0 to (ovTable.Rows.Length - 1) do  
begin
for j := 0 to (ovTable.Rows.Item(i).Cells.Length - 1) do
Begin
arrayn[i+1, j+1]:=ovTable.Rows.Item(i).Cells.Item(j).InnerText;
Application.ProcessMessages;
end;end;
WS.range[ws.cells[1, 1], ws.cells[ovTable.Rows.Length,     ovTable.Rows.Item(1).Cells.Length]].value:=arrayn;
Excel.WorkBooks[1].SaveAs(directorylistbox1.Directory+'\'+'test.xlsx');
WS := Excel.WorkBooks.close;
Excel.quit;
Excel:=unassigned;
```

HTML PARSING

```
function HTMLCleanUp(L : string) : string;
const
CSVTempSeparator = #255; //replaced by a comma
CRLF = #13#10;
var
P1,P2 : integer;
begin    
P1 := Pos('<',L); //clean-up anything between <>
while (P1>0) do    //WHILE1
begin
P2 := Pos('>',L);
if (P2>0)
then Begin Delete(L,P1,P2-P1+1); end;
P1 := Pos('<',L);
end;               //WHILE1
L:=StringReplace(L,'&nbsp;','-',[rfReplaceAll]);
L:=StringReplace(L,'-01','',[rfReplaceAll]);
L:=StringReplace(L,'-02','',[rfReplaceAll]);
L:=StringReplace(L,'-03','',[rfReplaceAll]);
Result := Trim(L);
end;

function HTMLTableToCSV(HTML,CSV : TStringList) : boolean;
const
CRLF = #13#10;
CSVTempSeparator = #9; 
var
P1,P2,P3,P4, p5, P6, p11, p22 : integer;
S,TmpStr,CSVStr : string;
begin
Result := True;
S := Trim(StringReplace(HTML.Text,CRLF,'',[rfReplaceAll]));
P1 := PosEx('<TR',S, 1);    //CASE SENSITIVE , TR->FIRST ROW
CSVStr := '';
while (P1>0) do     //while1
begin
P2 := PosEx('</TR',S, P1);
      if (P2>0)      //if1
      then begin
      TmpStr := Copy(S,P1,P2-P1+1);
      //Delete(S,P1,P2-P1+1);
      CSVStr := ''; p11:=1;p22:=1;
      P11 := PosEx('<TH',TmpStr,1);
            while (P11>0) do   //while2
            begin
            P22 := PosEx('</TH',TmpStr, P11);
                   if (P22>0)  //if2
                   then begin
                   CSVStr :=
                   //CSVStr+Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P1+4,P2-P1-4));//+CSVTempSeparator;
                   CSVStr+Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P11,P22-P11))+CSVTempSeparator;
                   //Delete(TmpStr,P1,P2-P1+1);
                   end        //if2
                   else begin
                   Result := False;
                   Exit;
                   end;       //if2
            P11 := PoseX('<TH',TmpStr, P22);
            end;              //while2
       P11 := PosEx('<TD',TmpStr, 1);
            while (P11>0) do   //while2
            begin
            P22 := PosEx('</TD',TmpStr, P11);
                   if (P22>0)  //if2
                   then begin
                   CSVStr :=
                   //CSVStr+Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P1+4,P2-P1-4));//+CSVTempSeparator;
                   CSVStr+Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P11,P22-P11))+CSVTempSeparator;
                   //Delete(TmpStr,P1,P2-P1+1);
                   end        //if2
                   else begin
                   Result := False;
                   Exit;
                   end;       //if2
             P11 := PosEx('<TD',TmpStr,P22);
            end;              //while2
      end            //if1
      else begin
      Result:=false;
      exit;
      end;            //if1
CSV.Add(HTMLCleanUp(CSVStr));
P1 := PosEx('<TR',S,P2);    //CASE SENSITIVE
end;      //while1
end;

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
xlExcel7 = $00000027;
TmpFileName='c:\test\Test.txt';
VAR
Excel: Olevariant;
HTMLStrList,CSVSTRList : TStringList;
begin
HTMLStrList := TStringList.Create;
try
HTMLStrList.LoadFromFile('C:\test\TestTable1.htm');
CSVSTRList := TStringList.Create;
try
if HTMLTableToCSV(HTMLStrList,CSVSTRList)
then Begin 
CSVSTRList.SaveToFile(TmpFileName);
Excel:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.WorkBooks.opentext(TmpFileName);//OPEN TXT WITH EXCEL
Excel.DisplayAlerts := False;
Excel.WorkBooks[1].SaveAs('c:\test\Nisa.xls', xlExcel7);//SAVE TAB DELIMITED TEXT FILE
Excel.WorkBooks[1].close;
Excel.quit;
Excel:=unassigned;
End
else ShowMessage('Error converting HTML table to CSV');
finally
CSVSTRList.Free;
end;
finally
HTMLStrList.Free;
DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
end;
end;


procedure TForm11.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
webBrowser1.Navigate('http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/tables/HTML_    Table.htm');
end;

procedure TForm11.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
var
Document: IHtmlDocument2;
CurWebrowser : IWebBrowser;
TopWebBrowser: IWebBrowser;
WindowName   : string;

begin
CurWebrowser := pDisp as IWebBrowser;
TopWebBrowser := (ASender as TWebBrowser).DefaultInterface;
if CurWebrowser=TopWebBrowser then
 begin
document := webbrowser1.document as IHtmlDocument2;
memo3.lines.add(trim(document.body.innerhtml));  // to get html
ShowMessage('Document is complete.')
 end;
end;
```

end.

Comment: Why is your code slow? Only you can answer because only you can see it.

Comment: I mean that it is hard for us to comment on your code if we cannot see it.

Comment: I added above the code

Comment: Where is the time taken? Is it extracting the data from the web browser? I'm not very keen on that call to `ProcessMessages`. At the very least you should not do that every time round the inner loop.

Comment: I am trying to extract the table from the webbrowser. The proccessMessages that you are saying is not the solution. The time taken is about 10 minutes vs the Export to excel" option of a classical webbrowser that it takes less than a minute for the specific table

Comment: I did not say that changing the call to `ProcessMessages` was the solution. I just don't like it. I'll ask my question one more time before giving up. *Where is the time taken? Is it extracting the data from the web browser?*

Comment: yes. that it says the above code

Comment: No it does not. For all I know, the time could be spent in the COM interop. Anyway if the time consuming part of the table extraction, you need to find a quicker way to do that. It's pointless including all the csv creation here. Make the question more focused. It should be "How can I extract the content of an HTML table quickly?" That would be a good question.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution...HTML Table Parsing in Less than a second!

```
function HTMLCleanUp(L : string) : string;
var
P1,P2 : integer;
begin
P1 := Pos('<',L); //clean-up anything between <>
while (P1>0) do    //WHILE1
begin
P2 := Pos('>',L);
if (P2>0)
then Begin Delete(L,P1,P2-P1+1); end;
P1 := Pos('<',L);
end;               //WHILE1
L:=StringReplace(L,'&nbsp;','-',[rfReplaceAll]);
Result := Trim(L);
end;

 procedure TForm11.WB_SaveAs_HTML(WB : TWebBrowser; const FileName : string) ;
 var
   PersistStream: IPersistStreamInit;
   Stream: IStream;
   FileStream: TFileStream;
 begin
   if not Assigned(WB.Document) then
   begin
     ShowMessage('Document not loaded!') ;
     Exit;
   end;

   PersistStream := WB.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
   FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate) ;
   try
     Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(FileStream, soReference) as IStream;
     if Failed(PersistStream.Save(Stream, True)) then ShowMessage('SaveAs HTML fail!') ;
   finally
     FileStream.Free;
   end;
 end; (* WB_SaveAs_HTML *)

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
xlExcel7 = $00000027;
TmpFileName='c:\test\xxxx.txt';
CRLF = #13#10;
CSVTempSeparator = #9;   //#255; //replaced by a comma
ADPNEWHOTURL = 'http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/tables/HTML_Table.htm';

VAR
Excel, WS: Olevariant;
P1,P2,P3,P4, p5, P6, p11, p22 : integer;
i, j: Integer;
buffer,rawHTM,TmpStr,CSVStr:string;
HTMFile : TextFile;
CSVSTRList : TStringList;

begin
CSVSTRList := TStringList.Create;

WB_SaveAs_HTML(WebBrowser1,TmpFileName) ;

AssignFile(HTMFile, TmpFileName);//read the HTML file
     Reset(HTMFile);
        while not EOF(HTMFile) do begin
        ReadLn(HTMFile, buffer);
        rawHTM := Concat(rawHTM, buffer);
      end;

i:=1;j:=1;
rawHTM := Trim(StringReplace(rawHTM,CRLF,'',[rfReplaceAll]));
P1 := PosEx('<TR',rawHTM, 1);   //CASE SENSITIVE , TR->FIRST ROW
while (P1>0) do     //while1
begin
P2 := PosEx('</TR',rawHTM, P1);
      if (P2>0)      //if1
      then begin
      TmpStr := Copy(rawHTM,P1,P2-P1+1);
      CSVStr := '';p11:=1;p22:=1;
      P11 := PosEx('<TH',TmpStr,1);
            while (P11>0) do   //while2
            begin
            P22 := PosEx('</TH',TmpStr, P11);
                   if (P22>0)  //if2
                   then begin
                   CSVStr :=CSVStr+
                   HTMLCleanUp(Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P11,P22-P11)))+CSVTempSeparator; j:=j+1;
                   end        //if2
                   else begin
                   Exit;
                   end;       //if2
            P11 := PoseX('<TH',TmpStr, P22);
            end;              //while2
       P11 := PosEx('<TD',TmpStr, 1);
            while (P11>0) do   //while2
            begin
            P22 := PosEx('</TD',TmpStr, P11);
                   if (P22>0)  //if2
                   then begin
                   CSVStr :=CSVStr+
                   HTMLCleanUp(Trim(Copy(TmpStr,P11,P22-P11)))+CSVTempSeparator; j:=j+1;
                   end        //if2
                   else begin
                   Exit;
                   end;       //if2
             P11 := PosEx('<TD',TmpStr,P22);
            end;              //while2
      end            //if1
      else begin
      exit;
      end;            //if1
      CSVSTRList.Add(CSVStr);
P1 := PosEx('<TR',rawHTM,P2); i:=i+1; j:=1;  //CASE SENSITIVE
end;      //while1

CSVSTRList.SaveToFile('c:\test\xxx2.txt');
Excel:= CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.WorkBooks.opentext('c:\test\xxx2.txt');//OPEN TXT WITH EXCEL
Excel.visible := True;
CloseFile(HTMFile);
DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
end;
```

Comment: That parsing is pretty dubious. You should use a real parser.

Comment: Please...I don't post it for you but to help somebody who searches for a solution regarding a quick method for HTML table parsing

Comment: I wouldn't recommend anybody use this code. The nice part though is where you export the HTML via a stream. A memory stream would be better but there you go.

Comment: That seems a little rude. If you don't read prose then you'll never learn anything.